# Mass Close Button on Case Object Should have Access Only for Few Users

Tags: case, button

Can any one help me on this ?

Standard Mass Close Button  on Case Object Should have Access Only for Few Profiles and in that profile only few users it should have Access .

For Example : Say for the Profile --Support Team ....I have Users As Tech1,Tech2,Tech3 ,Tech 4,Tech 5.Now i would like to give the "Mass Close" Button Access for the User Tech1 and Tech2 only.How can i do this.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: @Kaushik Ray ,@Ratan:Thanks for your response.Correct me if im wrong .But the Standard Close (Mass Close)button  on case object is not available on the pagelayouts.It appears only in Search layout for Case list View where we have all the the Buttons appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Idea [Visibility of a Custom Button Based on Profile](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br37AAC)

From Salesforce

> We definitely recognize the value that limiting the visibility of a
>   custom button based on profile would provide and the need it would
>   address, but aren't actively working on this at the moment.  We do
>   want to integrate this into a future roadmap (safe harbor), but it's
>   too early to provide specifics as to what that will look like/timing. 
>   In the meantime we're going to keep actively tracking on this one, and
>   will post a fresh update to the Idea once there are new developments.

Workaround for this to create different pagelayout for those user and remove the button from pagelayout. **(as @Kaushik Ray described)**

And assign the page layout to those use's profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating different page layouts for different profiles. So when you want to give access to certain profiles make sure you have the correct layout assigned.

Let me know if it helps or use case is different

Ray

Answer (score 0):

First create a permission set then select "Manage Cases" permission checkbox
permission set -> App Permissions -> check the "Manage Cases" permission checkbox and Assign the users that you want to give access.
thanks,
Rahul Kumar